# C++ - while(getline) doesn't get the first line of file

Tags: c++, reset, ifstream, getline

I've been working on a C++ program where I read a files contents and copy then onto another file but it always seem to skip the first line. I've seen others having trouble with this and they used these lines of code:

```
file.clear();
file.seekg(0);
```

to reset the position but its not working for me. I've tried it in multiple spots but still no luck. Any ideas? Heres my code.

```
ofstream write("Mar 23 2013.txt");

for(int x = 1; x <= 50; x++){

    stringstream ss;
    ss << "MAR23_" << x;

    ifstream file(ss.str().c_str());

    if(!file.is_open())
        cout << ss.str() << " could not be opened/found." << endl;
    else{  

        while(getline(file,line)){

            file >> time >> ch >> sensor1 >> ch >> temp >> ch >> 
                    sensor2 >> ch >> sensor3;

            file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            //output = convertEpoch(time);

            write << time << "  Temperature:" << temp << "ºF  S1:" <<
                        sensor1 << "  S2:" << sensor2 << "  S3:" << 
                        sensor3 << endl;

        }
        file.close();
    }  
}

write.close();

return 0;
```

Comment: Try printing out what line contains.  You'll see the first line of your file.  You can't read it twice. :)

Comment: I assume you're declaring a bunch of variables somewhere outside of this code block...

Comment: You read the first line with `getline` and then never use it. By that point the stream has moved past it.

Comment: Start getting used to writing for loops to the more idiomatic for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) instead of for(int i = 1; i <= 50; i++). You'll find that this will make your life much easier when you start dealing with arrays.

Comment: @Tomas yes this was just part of the code

Comment: @SecurityMatt yeah I usually do but I'm reading a bunch of files that start at MAR23_1 and end at MAR23_50 so I started the for loop at 1 to skim through those file names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing the first line because you read it in to `line`. In fact you should be missing more than just the first line.

Once you read from the file use a string stream.

```
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss>> time >> ch >> sensor1 >> ch >> temp >> ch >> 
                    sensor2 >> ch >> sensor3;
// ...


}
```

Comment: This answer would be even better if you also explained *why* =)

Comment: @stardust_ Wow! Swift response. And thank you, it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

You can read from a text file in basically two ways. Line by line, with `getline`, or item by item with `>>`. `getline` reads a line of text into its argument; after the call to `getline` in your code, `line` has the text that was read in. Having done that, the extractors in `file >> time >> ch ...` read from the spot where `getline` left off.